# Initializing Half Float textures (GL_HALF_FLOAT_OES) on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, precision

I'm looking into using Half Float (`GL_HALF_FLOAT_OES`) textures on iOS in certain places for their increased precision. But how do you initialize a texture with Half Float data?

If I were to use `glTexImage2D(…)` with a `data` buffer then I assume that it would need to contain half float data, but how would I convert 32-bit float data or 16-bit integer data into the half float format?

For example:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, w, h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_HALF_FLOAT_OES, data);
```

If I were to do that then `data` would need to contain a pointer to a half float buffer. But how do I convert existing data into half float? Is there a library or API call on iOS to do so? Or some other way to populate the texture?

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: Basically, you’re on your own as to how you convert the data to half float. There’s no API that I could find that will do it for you. There’s a good article here (ftp://www.fox-toolkit.org/pub/fasthalffloatconversion.pdf) on how to do fast half float conversions which I’m using to convert our internal data to half float before uploading via `glTexImage2D`.